# FullPage.js + class="section"

Tags: javascript, css, html5, fullpage.js

Estou utilizando o JS FullPage para fazer a ancoragem dos links, mas cada section fica com 100% de altura, além de as vezes atrapalhar em alguma coisa do meu css, que as vezes fica com um tamanho de letra maior ou posição errada. Queria saber se tem alguma coisa parecida com o fullpage?

Este é o `Script` utilizado

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myContainer').fullpage({
            anchors: ['Start', 'Devices', 'HowWeWork', 'FrequentlyAskedQuestions', 'Contact'],
            menu: '#menu',
            slidesNavigation: true,
            offsetSections: true,
            offsetSectionsKey: 'YWx2YXJvdHJpZ28uY29tX2ZZM2IyWm1jMlYwVTJWamRHbHZibk09MWpN'
        });
    });
```

basicamente queria que fizesse apenas a ancoragem dos links com o scroll, clicando nos links, ou apertando as teclas de navegação, mas que fosse com altura auto, igual a este exemplo:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/mediaqueries.html#anchor3

obs: já utilizei a classe `fp-auto-height` mas não rolou da maneira que quero.
obs2: se o conteúdo for maior que a página, também permitir rolagem como este exemplo: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrolloverflow-reset.html#secondPage

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo que você mesmo postou ele esta utilizando este JS para aplicar o fullPage, adicione as propriedades scrollOverflow, scrollOverflowReset, ao seu script para adicionar o overflow.

Da pra ler mais na documentação no [GitHub](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#use-extensions)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage'],
            sectionsColor: ['#475577', '#939FAA', '#4A6FB1', '#323539'],
            menu: '#menu',
            slidesNavigation: true,
            scrollOverflow: true,
            scrollOverflowReset: true,
            scrollOverflowResetKey: 'YWx2YXJvdHJpZ28uY29tXzlRaGMyTnliMnhzVDNabGNtWnNiM2RTWlhObGRBPT14Ykk='
        });
    });
```